# Eclipse WTP Tutorial Error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am following [WTP Tutorials Building and Running a Web Application](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html)

And when i run WebContent on the server(Tomcat 7) i get an error:

type Status report message /WTP-Tutorial-I/ description The requested resource (/WTP-Tutorial-I/) is not available.

Now on the tutorial it says it should direct me to /snoop , which it does not, but when i type it in manually (localhost:8080/WTP-Tutorial-I/snoop) it works any body know why this is?

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>WTP-Tutorial-I</display-name> 
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Snoop Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.eclipse.wtp.tutorial.SnoopServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Snoop Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/snoop/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Does it work when you right click the project (WTP-Tutorial-I) and try to run server on that instead of the WebContent folder?

Comment: I'm assuming it just isn't set up to launch from there and doesn't know what to do. Much like trying to launch a regular Java project from an improper place..

Comment: I have tried running it from the root of the project but i get the same error and the page it directs to is http://localhost:8080/WTP-Tutorial-I/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your web.xml configuration there is no default servlet or route. therefore when you navigate to

`localhost:8080/WTP-Tutorial-I`

it will give you an error `resource not found`.

but when you navigate to

`localhost:8080/WTP-Tutorial-I/snoop`

it runs the `org.eclipse.wtp.tutorial.SnoopServlet` which is mapped in the web.xml file.

i read the tutorial and they have not created any default servlet or route. in the "Running the Application" section of tutorial they say navigate to SnoopServlet by using this url

`http://localhost:8080/tutorial/snoop`

so you are following the tutorial in the right way. there is no error according to tutorial. 
one more thing, the tutorial is written in 2004, you need to search for some new tutorials since you are using tomcat 7.

Comment: according to the tutorial i can run the 'WebContent' on the server and it should direct me to http://localhost:8080/tutorial/snoop, but again it doesn't

Comment: Tutorial says you can run the "WebContent" on the server and then "you" will need to call your servlet which means calling http://localhost:8080/tutorial/snoop manually. you will not be redirected automatically. read the tutorial instruction carefully.